# Remove shadow on IIViewDeckController 2.2.11

Tags: ios, iiviewdeckcontroller

How to remove the shadow of the centerViewController on IIViewDeckController 2.2.11 ? I know I have to use a delegate that implements the viewDeckController:applyShadow:withBounds: selector. But I don't know how to do that.

If someone can help me. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found the solution for the version 2.2.11.

I added this to AppDelegate.h:

```
#import "IIViewDeckController.h"
@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate, IIViewDeckControllerDelegate>
```

In AppDelegate.m, in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions class:

```
deckController.delegate = self;
```

Then I added the viewDeckController:applyShadow:withBounds: selector to the end of AppDelegate.m:

```
- (void)viewDeckController:(IIViewDeckController *)viewDeckController applyShadow:(CALayer *)shadowLayer withBounds:(CGRect)rect {
    shadowLayer.masksToBounds = NO;
    shadowLayer.shadowRadius = 0;
    shadowLayer.shadowOpacity = 0;
    shadowLayer.shadowColor = nil;
    shadowLayer.shadowOffset = CGSizeZero;
    shadowLayer.shadowPath = nil;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a property in the IIViewDeckController called '**shadowEnabled**' simply set it to **NO** in your IIViewDeckController instance variable.

Alternatively in your Storyboard or .Xib file, you can add a *User Defined Runtime Attribute* with '**shadowEnabled**' as the Key Path, '**Boolean**' as the type and **uncheck** the value (making it NO/False)

Comment: To be honest, I'm unsure which version we are running, my apologies if these aren't present pre 2.3